# Scrollspy with Accordion?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

If you see image it has a box that will be in fixed position, as you scroll through sections the accordion will open up. I have scrollspy working but can't figure out how to get working with accordion using Bootstrap 4. Open to other alternatives.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You need to provide a better explanation of your problem. What exactly do you mean by 'a box that will be in a fixed position'?

Comment: post the code you have for that?